# How to navigate lock screen using keyboard?

Tags: macos, screen-lock

On the lock screen, I need to use mouse to select the user to login. I would like to navigate using the keyboard.

I tried Tab key, and combination with Ctrl and Option key, but can't find a way to navigate using keyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the left or right arrow key to highlight your chosen user, then press Enter to select.

Comment: You can also start typing the name of the user and it will be highlighted.